# Old review tool contradicts itself regarding the number of "first questions"

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, review-queue

The Phantom Menace:

[image: phantom post]

> I have to add some garble garble garble text here, because the site doesn't allow me to post the question, otherwise. Ignore this text here.

Comment: Mine shows the following question http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/22414/does-lily-potters-sacrifice-make-harry-and-voldemort-immortal

Comment: As does mine... Though now that I look at it, it also tells me 48 posts under first answers on the main "review" screen, but then zero when I click the link.

Comment: For me, on the list of review lists, it shows 48 First Answers, 1 First Question, and 41 Late Answers.  After clicking through, all of them show 1 post in both the header and the list.  (The one showing up on both First Answer/Late Answer happened after @NominSim posted)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way this can happen is [if you have ignored tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/113378/review-page-says-1-post-but-nothing-is-shown).

Beyond that... I don't have much other than "huh, that's weird."

Since we're now pouring efforts into the new /review and these old queues will eventually be replaced, this is probably not worth fixing.

Comment: I do. One of them ([tag:harry-potter]) is tremendously popular, so that's probably the reason.

Comment: @bitmask I'm gonna go with [status-bydesign] then. :)